# Angular virtual scroll reset to top

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cdk, virtualscroll, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

In my [Angular](https://angular.io/) app, I'm using the [Virtual Scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) from the Angular cdk.

This is my Component's template:

```html
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" class="example-viewport">
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items" class="example-item">{{item}}</div>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

In my Component's class, I have a method that changes the array `items` giving to it new contents. The size of the array can change every time this method is called:

```js
reload(newItems) {
  this.items = newItems;
}
```

After calling the method `reload`, the array of items is correctly updated and the view reflects this change. However, the scroll doesn't go back on top.

I would like to have the virtual scrolling to reset the scroll on top every time the `items` array is changed.

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by injecting a `CdkVirtualScrollViewport` inside my Component:

```js
import { CdkVirtualScrollViewport } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';

// ...
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport) virtualScroll: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  // ...

  reload(newItems) {
    this.items = newItems;
    this.virtualScroll.scrollToIndex(0);
  }
}
```

Calling `this.virtualScroll.scrollToIndex(0);` did the trick.

Comment: So if we are using multiple cdkvirtualscroll  means how can we reset the scrollToIndex(0)
Refer the Ex:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vcohv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html